# How to initialize c++/cx class with aggregate initialization?

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have this ref class:

```
namespace N 
{       
  public ref class S sealed
  {
    public:
      property Platform::String^ x;
  };
}
```

How do I initialize it in place with the aggregate initializer?
I have tried:

```
N::S s1 = { %Platform::String(L"text") };
```

but the compiler says

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
>   'N::S'

Also:

```
N::S s1 { %Platform::String(L"text") };
```

and the error is:

> error C2664: 'N::S::S(const N::S %)': cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'Platform::String ^' to 'const N::S %'

This works greatly with the standard c++ like this:

```
struct T
    {
        wstring x;
    };
T x { L"test" };
```

I do not want to use a constructor here.

Comment: Your ref class is an interop type, the property is not actually a field in the class.  Just convenient syntax sugar for a C++ programmer.   But it requires calling a function (set_x) to initialize the value, incompatible with an initializer list.  You need `s1.x = "test";`, the compiler automagically creates the Platform::String and converts it to an interface method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean you don't want a `public` constructor on the projected WinRT type -- no problem, you can use the `internal` keyword to mean "public inside C++ but not exposed through interop". That means you can even use native C++ types for your parameters if you like:

```
namespace Testing
{
  public ref class MyTest sealed
  {
  public:
    property String^ Foo { 
      String^ get() { return m_foo; }
      void set(String^ value) { m_foo = value; }
    }

  internal:
    // Would not compile if it was public, since wchar_t* isn't valid
    MyTest(const wchar_t* value) { m_foo = ref new String(value); }

  private:
    String^ m_foo;
  };
}

MainPage::MainPage()
{
  // Projected type does NOT have this constructor
  Testing::MyTest t{ L"Hello" };
  OutputDebugString(t.Foo->Data());
  t.Foo = "\nChanged";
  OutputDebugString(t.Foo->Data());
}
```

Also you don't need to have the `private` variable to hold the string -- you could just use the auto-property as in your original code -- but I prefer to be explicit. It also means that if you needed to access the string a lot from within your C++ code you could provide an `internal` accessor function and not have to go through a vtable call to get at it.

Comment: Thank you @Peter! Quite a bit of additional code in the class, but it's ok since it saves me one line on the calling side.